# Cake php 2.x what is necessary of .po file and how to write translation word in .po file?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am wondering about multilanguage in cake php. how to write transaction in .po file.
i want to use two language that is English and French, now i created two default.po file in the below path

```
/app/Locale/eng/LC_MESSAGES/default.po (English)
/app/Locale/fra/LC_MESSAGES/default.po (French)
```

how to access the default.po file and what i have to write inside default.po file

please help me to find out solution.

Thanks Sanjib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. MINIMUM to check how it works**

In Your **View** use function `__()`, for example, write in English (main language):

```
<?php echo __('My name is Tom');?>
```

Then in Your `.po` file for French /app/Locale/fra/LC_MESSAGES/**default.po** translate:

```
msgid "My name is Tom"
msgstr "Mon nom est Tom"
```

You can use [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/download.php) or good PHP editor (UTF-8) like [eclipse](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt/downloads)

Then in Your **controller** - can be `AppController.php` -> `public function beforeFilter()` You can set Your language like:

```
$this->Session->write('Config.language', 'fra');
```

and...
don't forget to set Your main language in `/Config/core.php` like:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'eng');
```

and use session component - in Your controller:

```
public $components = array('Session');
```

**2. FOR COMPLETE MULTILANGUAGE SYSTEM** 
You need to:

- add function to **init language** like `$this->_setLanguage();` to get language from URL params
- add function to **switch language** with links in Your view/site layout with language param
- **set routing** in Your Config/routes.php
- can extends HtmlHelper to add language param to all your links, like:

> App::uses('HtmlHelper', 'View/Helper');
>       class MyHtmlHelper extends HtmlHelper {
>
> ```
>     public function url($url = null, $full = false) {
>
>        if(!isset($url['language']) && isset($this->params['language'])) {
>           $url['language'] = $this->params['language'];
>         }
>         return parent::url($url, $full);
>    }
> }
> ```

**UPDATE:**

table with **locale field** for all languages: http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-L10n.html#177-326

Comment: You are absolutely right, when i set default language in core.php 
onfigure::write('Config.language', 'eng');  that works fine

but when i change the English to French, in beforeFilter()

$this->Session->write('Config.language', 'fre');

the french version would not work.

finally in English version works fine but not work on French version

Comment: You should use 'fra' instead of 'fre' - sorry, my mistake

Comment: I also used 'fra' but after getting your feedback i used 'fre' both are not working

Comment: Did you find a solution 3 years later ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this basic guide in the CakePHP book: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html.

The specific answer to your question: After generating the po-files through cake, you should open them with a translation program (po-edit for example). There you can insert all the translation. After that, the program will write to the po-file and generate a mo-file. CakePHP should automatically read those and localize your app!